# Is there a method somewhere supplied by Apple which will trigger when a UIWebView changes pages?

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview

I am trying to change the size of a webView when the website changes.  What I need is to check the UIWebview's URL to see if it matches the one I am looking for.  Or just changes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol in your view controller, you can handle the following [message](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

and get the URL as a string:

```
NSString * urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;
```

**Update**

Make sure you set the [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate) property on the *UIWebView*.

Comment: So would this also make sense?

Because it does not say hit

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

{
 
 NSLog(@"HIT");
 
}

Comment: are you setting yourself as a delegate on the UIWebView?

Comment: @michael-amici Happy to help.  If this answer was helpful, you can upvote and/or click accept answer. :)